# In YML is it possible to add jobs or stages on top of an extended template?

Tags: azure, yaml, continuous-integration, environment-variables, cicd

I'm trying to add on some extra jobs and stage steps onto my pipeline in Azure Devops to be able to load in a `.env` file into the build process.

The pipeline needs to go and grab the `.env` file and then place it in the directory we need it to exist in before the template goes and builds the application.

My current pipeline code:

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: TemplateRepo
      type: git
      ref: refs/tags/App1
      name: TemplateRepo

extends:
  template: TemplateFile.yml
  parameters:
    stages:
      - stage: PreBuild
        displayName: PreBuild
        jobs:
          - job: PreBuild
            steps:
              - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
                inputs:
                  secureFile: ".env"
              - task: CopyFiles@2
                inputs:
                  targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

trigger:
  batch: true
```

I keep running into an error with adding stages as they're not a parameter of the template? Would I need to add stages as a parameter then on the template to be able to add in new jobs? Or can I get around this somehow and get the jobs to run before the template is used?

What options do I have here to make this work how I'm intending it?

Comment: Is there an answer or some kind of hint to this problem, I also ran into the same problem.